# Как узнать id потока интерфейсного окна?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi, hook

Есть сторонний процесс с gui, в котором запущено несколько потоков. Нужно установить hook клавиатуры на поток gui этого процесса. Делаю следующим образом:

```
 processID = 8888; //pid 
 HWND hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
 DWORD threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &processID);
 hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC)&KeyboardProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), threadID);
```

`processId` ввожу вручную из диспетчера задач (для отладки, потом он будет возвращаться скриптом). Если заменить параметр `threadID` в последней строке на 0, то hook работает, но работает везде - даже в браузере. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моей задаче очень важно было, чтобы метод установки hook и метод KeyboardProc были в одной области кода (.cpp), а не в разных dll . Я нашел ответ:

1) Делаем глобальную переменную `processID`

2) в методе установки hook

```
processID = GetCurrentProcessId();
  hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC)&KeyboardProc, NULL, 0);
```

3) В методе KeyboardProc:

```
DWORD actProcess;
 HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
 GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &actProcess);
 if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
 {
  if (processID == actProcess)
  {
    //do something
  } 
 }
```